# What is the convenient way to state the meaning that being bored in the past?

Tags: grammar

So, actually, I would like to form the sentence that includes "bored" in the past perfect continous.

Is it right, if I say: "I had been being bored." ? Or what would be the right way to say that a person was being bored during in a particular time in the past ?

Comment: FYI, we have a site dedicated to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You quite simply just say:

> I was bored.

Comment: But the meaning that I want to specify is different than, I was bored, I guess.

Comment: @Yirmidokuz I don’t see how.  “It was a day when nothing was supposed to happen, and almost did. I was at home just waiting for nothing to happen, and horribly bored with life, when the meteor annihilated my barn.”  You are going to have to supply a great deal more context and examples if you want some subtler sense. And I somewhat doubt anyone would actually use it even if so.